# how get text value of name option in k8s yaml file

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes

I have many k8s deployment files with yaml format.

I need to get the value of the first occurrence of name option only inside these files.

Example of deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

I need to get only the value `nginx-deployment`

I tried, but no success:

```
grep 'name: ' ./deployment.yaml | sed -n -e 's/name: /\1/p'
```

Comment: And you don't say so, but are these descriptors applied to a cluster, or you trying to analyze them before you apply them?  If they are already applied to the cluster, then you print those objects with "kubectl get ... -o json" and pipe them to "jq", or even use "-o=jsonpath='{.metadata.name}'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed`. Find first row with `name`, remove everything before `:`  and  `:`  and then quit `sed`.

```
sed -n '/name/{ s/.*: //; p; q}' deployment.yaml
```

Output:

```
nginx-deployment
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have `yq` installed(similar to `jq`) for yaml,  this is a yaml aware tool and perhaps a robust tool for parsing yaml.

```
yq e '.metadata.name' deployment.yaml
nginx-deployment
```

Using awk :

```
awk -v FS="[: ]" '/name:/{print $NF;exit}'  deployment.yaml
nginx-deployment
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`(1) that supports the `-P` flag.

```
grep -m1 -Po '(?<=name: ).*' deployment.yaml
```